# How to read ip and port from text file and put in firewall

Tags: iptables, firewall, ipset

I decided to use iptables and ipset to read text file that contains source ip and destination port. I want to drop these flows. Is it possible and how to write command to perform this?

The file is:

```
192.45.67.89,22
54.123.212.51,22
123.12.15.46,23
...
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. The only valid answer to how, is to quote the manual at you. However take a look at nftables, it replaces iptables and is easier to learn and use.

Comment: To expand on what @ctrl-alt-delor said, look in the man pages for `ipset` at the `hash:ip,port` section. And for iptables look at the `iptables-extensions` manpage under the `SET` section.